# Obfuscating android malware

Tags: malware, obfuscation

I am exploring android malware forensics and am trying out payload generation and delivery, while also trying obfuscation. I have used commercial tools, e.g. ProGuard and also open sourced tools, eg. Obfuscapk. Now I am trying to advance further with my own obfuscation techniques, but am not sure where to start exploring and trying obfuscation on my own instead of relying on tools. Where can I start/learn more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very open ended, so it's a little hard to be specific enough to be helpful.  I would suggest looking outside Android at (a) techniques used to detect malware and (b) techniques used to avoid detection.

As an example, some malware scanners look for specific binary string matching a payload, and the response from malware writers is along the lines of Metamorphic Code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphic_code)... which is basically having the code swap out different instructions with identical outcomes (eg, replace x = 5; with x = 3; x+=2;).  Similarly, some applications will compress & encrypt their payload code and build in a decompression/decryption routine.

Note that malware detection is usually a proprietary game, so usually your best bet is to start with the specific detection tools and try different things to see what it is they're picking up on exactly.